# Replacing Shell Pipeline

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the Python 2.7 documentation of subprocess module, I found the following snippets:

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Source : https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

I don't understand this line : `p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.`

Here p1.stdout is being closed. How does it allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits?

Answer (score 5):

The SIGPIPE signal is normally sent if a process attempts to write to a pipe from which no active process is looking.  In the shell pipeline equivalent of your code snippet:

```
`dmesg | grep hda`
```

If the `grep` process for some reason terminates before `dmesg` is done writing output, `dmesg` will receive a SIGPIPE and terminate itself.  This would be the expected behavior for UNIX/Linux processes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal).

By contrast, in the Python implementation using `subprocess`, if `p2` exits before `p1` is done generating output, the SIGPIPE doesn't get sent because there is actually still a process looking at the pipe - the Python script itself (the one which created `p1` and `p2`).  More importantly, the script is looking at the pipe but not consuming its contents - the effect is that the pipe is held open indefinitely and `p1` gets stuck in limbo.

Explicitly closing `p1.stdout` detaches the Python script from the pipe and makes it such that no process other than `p2` is looking at the pipe - that way if `p2` does end before `p1`, `p1` properly gets the signal to end itself without anything artificially holding the pipe open.

Here is an alternatively worded explanation:
http://www.enricozini.org/2009/debian/python-pipes/

Comment: "a pipe from which no active process is looking" and "still a process looking at the pipe" are not really precise wordings.

Answer (score 3):

A hopefully more systematic explanation:

- A pipe is an instance managed by the operating system. It has a single read end and a single write end.
- Both ends can be opened by multiple processes. There is still only one pipe, though. That is, multiple processes can share the same pipe.
- A process that has opened one of the ends holds a corresponding file handle. The process can actively `close()` it again! If a process exits, the operating system closes the corresponding file handle for you.
- All involved processes can `close()` their file handle representing the read end of the pipe. Nothing wrong with that, this is a perfectly fine situation.
- Now, if a process writes data to the write end of the pipe and the read end is not opened anymore (no process holds an open file handle for the read end), a POSIX-compliant operating system sends a `SIGPIPE` signal to the *writing* process for it to *know* that there is no reader anymore.

This is the standard mechanism by which the receiving program can *implicitly* tell the sending program that it has stopped reading. Have you ever wondered if

```
cat bigfile | head -n5
```

actually reads the entire bigfile? No, it does not, because `cat` retrieves a `SIGPIPE` signal as soon as `head` exits (after reading 5 lines from stdin). The important thing to appreciate: `cat` has been designed to actually *respond* to `SIGPIPE` (that is an important engineering decision ;)): it stops reading the file and exits. Other programs are designed to ignore `SIGPIPE` (on purpose, these handle this situation on their own -- this is common in networking applications).

If you keep the read end of the pipe open in your controlling process, you disable described mechanism. `dmesg` will not be able to notice that `grep` has exited.

However, your example actually is not a good one. `grep hda` will read the *entire* input. `dmesg` is the process that exits first.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
The p1.stdout.close() call after starting the p2 is important in order for p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits before p1.
```

The SIGPIPE signal is sent to a process when it attempts to write to a pipe without a process connected to the other end. When p2 is created using `stdin=p1.stdout`, there are two processes connected to the pipe `p1.stdout`: the parent python process and p2. Even when p2 closes prematurely, the parent process is still running, thus, SIGPIPE signal is not sent. `p1.stdout.close()` closes `p1.stdout` in the parent/caller process, thus leaving dmesg as the only process with that file descriptor open.

In other words, if there is no `p1.stdout.close()` then:

- `p1.stdout` remains open in the parent process. If p2 exits (i.e. there is
  no one to read p1.stdout), p1 won't know that nobody reads
  `p1.stdout` and will continue to write to `p1.stdout` until the
  corresponding OS pipe buffer is full.
- in case p2 exits prematurely, `p1.stdout` would still be
  open in the parent process, thus SIGPIPE won't be generated.