# Setting up a pipeline using subprocess.Popen: Why close stdout but not stdin?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

The Python 3 documentation for `subprocess.popen` ([1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)) presents the following sample code for pipelines:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

> The p1.stdout.close() call after starting the p2 is important in order for p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits before p1.

Why is this necessary? Previous questions ([Replacing Shell Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796317/replacing-shell-pipeline), [Under what condition does a Python subprocess get a SIGPIPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190250/under-what-condition-does-a-python-subprocess-get-a-sigpipe), [Explain example from python subprocess module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046779/explain-example-from-python-subprocess-module)) have answers stating that `p1.stdout` has multiple readers, which must all be closed to prevent `p1`'s output pipe from closing.

---

What is the relation between `p2.stdin` and `p1.stdout`, and do I have to close `p2.stdin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not have to close `p2.stdin`. In fact you can't, because it's None.

This is because `stdin=p1.stdout`, while a Python stream object is only created if `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`. See [subprocess Popen.stdin docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin))

---

I wrote a test program (Python 3) which terminates with `BrokenPipeError` if `CLOSE_P1 = True`, but spins forever?? if `CLOSE_P1 = False`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


CLOSE_P1 = True


p1 = Popen("ffmpeg "
           "-f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 1x1 -i - "
           "-c copy -f rawvideo -".split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
assert p2.stdin is None

if CLOSE_P1:
    p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
p2.terminate()
while 1:
    p1.stdin.write(b'fsdafhdsf9jd9s8ha0')
```